# What is the meaning of errors of separate variables in a fit?

Tags: regression

When doing a least-square fitting of a two-parameter function (e.g. $y=a+bx$) with specialised software like Origin or gnuplot, one gets errors for the resulting $a$ and $b$. What do these errors mean exactly?